# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/EjemploITextPDF/1560722023-07-31 07:14.pdf: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, itextpdf

Cuento con el siguiente codigo para generar un archivo pdf con itext en android, el archivo me lo habia estado generando correctamente de igual manera se visualizaba correctamente pero de pronto dejo de visualizar y al revisar el logcat solo me muestra que no puede abrir el archivo

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/EjemploITextPDF/1560722023-07-31 07:14.pdf: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

Y al seguir revisando el logcat me marca error en la linea
`var fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)`

Y al revisar la carpeta donde deberia estar el archivo no lo esta creando ya

Anexo el codigo de creacion

```
@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    fun crearPdf() {

        val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).absolutePath + "/EjemploITextPDF"

        val dir = File(path)
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs()

        val file = File(dir, userName + fecha + ".pdf")

        try {

            //creamos el flujo de datos de salida
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

            val documento = Document(PageSize.A4.rotate())
            documento.setMargins(1f,1f,25f,1f)

            //asociamos el flujo al documento
            val pdfw = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, fileOutputStream)

            // abrimos el documento y le agregamos contenido
            documento.open()


            var tabla2 =PdfPTable(1)
            val celdaFinal = PdfPCell(Paragraph("OPEN PICKING TASK with Available Inventory", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 22f, Font.BOLD)))

            // Indicamos cuantas columnas ocupa la celda
            celdaFinal.setColspan(9);
            celdaFinal.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            celdaFinal.setPaddingTop(10f)
            celdaFinal.setPaddingBottom(12f)

            //Configuramos el grosor y color de los bordes de la celda
            celdaFinal.setBorderWidth(2f);
            celdaFinal.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);

            tabla2.addCell(celdaFinal)

            documento.add(tabla2)

            val titulo = Paragraph(" \n",FontFactory.getFont("arial", 22f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE))
            titulo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val ID = PdfPCell(Paragraph("ID", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            ID.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val PLANTA = PdfPCell(Paragraph("PLANTA", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            PLANTA.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val REQUISICION = PdfPCell(Paragraph("REQUISICION", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            REQUISICION.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val MATERIAL = PdfPCell(Paragraph("MATERIAL", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            MATERIAL.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val ZONA = PdfPCell(Paragraph("ZONA", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            ZONA.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val RACK = PdfPCell(Paragraph("RACK", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            RACK.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val PQ_TASK = PdfPCell(Paragraph("PQ_TASK", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            PQ_TASK.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val DUE_DATE = PdfPCell(Paragraph("DUE_DATE", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            DUE_DATE.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            val QTY_TO_PICK = PdfPCell(Paragraph("QTY_TO_PICK", FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f, Font.BOLD)))
            QTY_TO_PICK.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

            documento.add(titulo)

            var tabla = PdfPTable(9)
            tabla.setWidths(intArrayOf(2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5))

            tabla.addCell(ID)
            tabla.addCell(PLANTA)
            tabla.addCell(REQUISICION)
            tabla.addCell(MATERIAL)
            tabla.addCell(ZONA)
            tabla.addCell(RACK)
            tabla.addCell(PQ_TASK)
            tabla.addCell(DUE_DATE)
            tabla.addCell(QTY_TO_PICK)

            for (item in listaUsuarios) {
                val celdaID = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.id_pickeo, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaID.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaP = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.planta, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaP.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaR = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.requisicion, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaR.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaM = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.material_number, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaM.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaZ = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.zona, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaZ.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaRa = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.rack_location, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaRa.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaD = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.due_date, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaD.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val celdaQ = PdfPCell(Paragraph(item.qty_to_pick, FontFactory.getFont("arial", 12f)))
                celdaQ.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

                val img: Image

                val code128 = Barcode128()
                code128.setCodeType(Barcode.CODE128);
                code128.setCode("0" + item.po_task_id);
                img = code128.createImageWithBarcode(pdfw.getDirectContent(),
                    BaseColor.BLACK,
                    BaseColor.BLACK
                )

                tabla.addCell(celdaID).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaP).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaR).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaM).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaZ).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaRa).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(img)
                tabla.addCell(celdaD).setPaddingTop(20f)
                tabla.addCell(celdaQ).setPaddingTop(20f)

            }

            documento.add(tabla)

            documento.close()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Se genero correctamente el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PdfVista::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        } catch (e: Exception){

            e.printStackTrace()

        }
    }
```

Lo que descubri es que si cambio la ubicacion de almacenamiento del archivo por ejemplo de `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` a `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` y ejecuto la aplicacion si me crea el archivo y lo visualiza pero solo por un tiempo determinado.